# Passing Int as void* then getting the value

Tags: c++, pointers, void-pointers

I am using a Timer class that takes a void* as an optional arguement to pass to the callback. I need to pass an integer but my logic doesn't seem to be working out to well.

In Event_PlayerSpawn() I have a int* clientIndex that is pointing to the memory location of the int "client". I pass this into the void* param, and then in the callback cast it to an int* again, then dereference it to get the value. Where exactly am I going wrong?

```
ResultType PlayerSpawnTimer::OnTimer(ITimer *pTimer, void *pData)
{
    int client = *((int*)pData);
    ConquestPlayer *pPlayer = dynamic_cast<ConquestPlayer*>(CEntity::Instance(client));

    Msg("Spawn Timer Called client = %d!\n", client);
    if(pPlayer)
    {
        pPlayer->FindSpawnLocation();
    }

    return Pl_Continue;
}

void GameManager::Event_PlayerSpawn(IGameEvent *event)
{
    int client = engine->IndexOfEdict(GetEdictOfUserID(event->GetInt("userid")));

    int *clientIndex = &client;
    // Add a 0.1 second delay then handle spawn location
    timerPlayerSpawn = timersys->CreateTimer(&playerSpawnTimerCallback, 5.0, clientIndex, 0);
}
```

Comment: Could you please be more specific? Do you have compilation error? So what's the error error message is and on which line do you have it? Or it is runtime error?

Comment: Runtime error, it is coming out as 0 in the callback, but when passed it is different (changes at runtime, but between 1-33).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to allocate memory for variable. But for now it's in stack and destroyed when you leave `Event_PlayerSpawn`.

```
int *clientIndex = new int[1];
clientIndex[0] = client;
```

Comment: No need to create an array for this: `new int(client)` would have worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
timerPlayerSpawn = timersys->CreateTimer(&playerSpawnTimerCallback, 5.0,(void *) client, 0);
```

And in the callback:

```
int client = (int)pData;
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about the timersys->CreateTimer implementation, but "int client" is local to Event_PlayerSpawn and is probably deallocated by the time PlayerSpawnTimer::OnTimer is invoked.

If you really need to pass a void * instead of an int, you might need to use "new" and "delete" to ensure the memory for "int client" gets allocated and deallocated properly.